# flask GET PATCH endpoints overwriting

Tags: rest, flask

If I try to have two separate methods for the same same route,
I get an error if I try to request the second route.  If I place
the in the same route decorator ['GET', 'PATCH'] it seems to work.
What does this happen?

```
`
@scans_blueprint.route(
    '/scans/<string:scan_id>',
    methods=['GET']
)

scans_blueprint.route(
    '/scans/<string:scan_id>',
    methods=['PATCH']
)
`
```

I am expecting the second route to work with the given setup but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know you need to combine the two methods, and then branch with if-statements inside the route

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/your_route', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def your_route():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # do get stuff
    elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        # do patch stuff
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

alternatively, you could use flask-restful and implement the methods using two completely separate functions - this might be what you're thinking of

```
class YourRoute(Resource):
    def get():
        # do get stuff

    def patch():
        # do patch stuff
```

https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api